# drupal how to limit the display results of the calendar view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

i have a calendar view its working pretty fine,,, 
but i need to restrict the results to one per date, if i have five events, my view looks odd
so thought of adding a more link and displaying only one result per date.....

is there any way to this,, i have tried limiting the view to display the results to 1 
but it doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't this kind of ruin the whole point of a calendar (i.e., all the information on one page)?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a similar functionality by changing calendar template files.  The one I've used is calendar-datebox.tpl.php (it formats the date in each cell of a calendar, but I used this one because other calendar templates don't seem to contain all variables I needed).

Copy the default version to your theme and try to play with it.  You will see there is a bunch of useful variables, one of them is:

```
// $items: An array of items for this day.
```